# unable to parse unmarshall xsi:nil=true with jibx

Tags: apache-axis, jibx

I am receiving a soap message from an external server that is sending xsi:nil tag for a boolean element.

JIBX complains about an invalid boolean value and its not able to parse this xml.

How can I overcome this problem?

incoming xml:

```
<materialChange xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:nil="true"/>
```

the xsd:

```
<s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="materialChange" type="s:boolean" nillable="true"/>
```